# Ajax dependent dropdown value is not fetching the values

Tags: php, ajax

In my page I have the following code

**hostadd.php**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp=false;  
    try{
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)    {       
        try{            
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e){
            try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
                xmlhttp=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}

function getState(countryId) {      
    var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
}       
}

</script>


<div style="margin-left: 51px;">State:
    <select name="country" id="country" onChange="getState(this.value)" style="margin-left: -3px;">
        <option ></option>

        <?php $qr = mysql_query("select * from ctm_state ");

        while($data= mysql_fetch_array($qr))

        {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['state']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**findstate.php**

```
<? $country=intval($_GET['country']);
include("../config/config.php");
$query="SELECT id,location FROM ctm_locationname WHERE stateid='$country'";
echo $query;
$result=mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "cant fetch";
}
?>
<div  style=""> location:<select name="state" id="state">
<option></option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['location']?>><?=$row['location']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select></div>
```

But it shows the error of "There was problem using xml http request" . I cant find what mistake is done by me. Anyone can help me to solve this problem

Comment: What is the difficulties to use jquery+ajax?

Comment: refer this for proper xml object. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp

Comment: this is an simple ajax example to help you understand things. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Comment: Have you try with `findState.php?country=1` something like this. Are you sure the file permission of `findstate.php` is ok?

Comment: please used req.open("GET", strURL, true); before req.onreadystatechange function instead of using it at the end of function please try and see it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pressume your `var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;` is not proper.

Check your browser error console, you can see errors there.

If it is showing 404 page not found, It is because your strURL is not proper check the spelling or path.